# Android: KeyListener for an EditText not receiving keys

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener

I have an EditText that I want to monitor KeyEvents for, and I have a listener set up as follows:

```
mText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.title);
mText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        final int view = v.getId();
        switch (view) {
            case R.id.title:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "key handled");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

My problem is that when the EditText is being typed into using the virtual keyboard, the only key press that triggers the logging is the backspace key.  I've verified that all other keypresses aren't even triggering `onKey()`.  I'm sure this is something simple, but didn't find anything on SO that seemed to deal with this.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: From the documentation `Key presses on soft input methods are not required to trigger the methods in this listener, and are in fact discouraged to do so. The default android keyboard will not trigger these for any key to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only deliver it for some key presses to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier.` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)` defined [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) with it you can handle the physical and the soft keyboard.
I hope it helps

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for - still strange behavior on the key listener, but thanks for this.

Answer (score 6):

From the Android reference at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

View.OnKeyListener

Class Overview
Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before the key event is given to the view. This is only useful for hardware keyboards; **a software input method has no obligation to trigger this listener.**

It seems OnKeyListener is designed expressly to react to HARDWARE keys only!

Answer (score -1):

`onKeyListener` only works with:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Set it in the `onCreate` method.